# Navigate to same screen but from two different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I have 3 VC

```
ViewController1,ViewController2,ViewController3
```

Now I have a button in `ViewController2` and `ViewController3`, which on tapping navigates to `ViewController1`
there is a slight change in the UI of when navigating from vc2 and when from vc3.

So I want to know the best practice of handling this problem ie. how would I know from which vc have I reached to `VC1`.?

Comment: You are pushing the ViewController1 from ViewController2 and ViewController3? or dismissing the controller

Comment: yes I am pushing the Viewcontroller1 from ViewController2 and ViewController3

Comment: When you go back to VC1 you are poping the controller?

Comment: from vc2 and vc3 I push vc1 respectively, then from vc1 I pop the controller, so return to the previous screen (vc2/3 whichever it was)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a flag or enum. I suggest for enum bcz sometimes in future you might push from multiple controllers to VC1. Its always handy to use a enum.

> 1. With flag

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    // default value is false bcz if you forgot to assign this value then atleast your app won't crash.
    var isFromVC2 : Bool = false
        :
        :
}
```

- **Use ->** In your VC1 file

  ```
  if isFromVC2 {
      // Do code for VC2
  }
  else {
      // Do code for VC3
  }
  ```

> 2. With Enum

```
enum ComingFrom {
    case VC3
    case VC2
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // default value VC2
    var whichController : ComingFrom = .VC2
      :
      :
}
```

- Use

  ```
  switch whichController {
      case .VC2:
          // for vc2 Code
      case .VC3:
          // for VC3 Code
      default:
          // If you forget to assign `whichController` or there will be new condition in future
  }
  ```

> Edit : How to assign whichController

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
vc.whichController = .VC2
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

- **For More Clearity**

[image]

Comment: okay, and how should I pass which controller value to VC1 from vc2 and vc3?

Answer (score 1):

In your VC1, create a variable as vcNames.

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
        var vcNames = ""
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Check your vc's with vcNames.
   }
}
```

Now while pushing to vc1 from VC2 or VC3, Just pass your current vc name with created variable.

```
 let tempVC1 = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1") as? VC1
 tempVC1?.vcNames =  "vc2" //Assign your vc name here
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tempVC1!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Its creates highly changes of typo. **NEVER EVER DO THIS.**

Answer (score 1):

Add unique `Bool` variable so you can understand where to come to this controller. 
Make `flag false` in `viewWillAppear` because every time it should be updated its a simplest way that you can achieve.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
      var isFromVC2 = false
      var isFromVC3 = false

     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         super.viewWillAppear(true)
         isFromVC2 = false
         isFromVC3 = false
     }

}


class ViewController2: UIViewController {


 //You can call this function from where you want otherwise you can make it global.
    func navigateToVC1() {
        let viewController1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        viewController1.isFromVC2 = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController1, animated: true)
    }


}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    func navigateToVC1() {
        let viewController1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController1") as! ViewController1
        viewController1.isFromVC3 = true
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController1, animated: true)
    }

}
```